# Positive Definite Test through Inner Product of a Matrix with Itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, positive-definite

I am looking at the [youtube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVHBhs6x2AM&t=11m11s) on determining positive semidefitiness by taking inner product of say (2x2) vector. The lecturer shows the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a 
\end{pmatrix}$$

but then he mentions if you compute inner product of vector $(x,y)$ with itself, we get the following expression:

$$ax^2+2bxy+by^2 >0$$

I would like to ask how did he jump from the above matrix to this expression? say the matrix above is $A$, taking inner product of itself do we have to do this? $AA^T$?

Comment: A symmetric matrix defines a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) by $v^TAv$. This explains the jump. Here $v^T=(x,y)$.

Comment: Also, the expression is $ax^2+2bxy+a y^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat so the expression in the video is wrong?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the formula you wrote is the inner product?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER: I didn't look at the video. Just compute the expression directly. To simplify, set $b=0$ then the expression should be $a(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: @copper.hat well in the video its $ax^2+2bxy+b y^2$ I got the same when i expanded the $v^TAv$ so technically that is also the inner product, right?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER: I am not sure what you are referring to by same and I not sure what you are referring to as the inner product. Just to clarify, a $by^2$ term would be incorrect as is easily verified and the map $(u,v) \mapsto u^Tv$ is an inner product, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat yes I was looking for the inner product formula so I can check myself what that shall be in quadratic form. so if the matrix that I mentioned in the question the inner product formula of that matrix with itself would $v^TAv$ where $v$ is $(x,y)$ and $A$ is the matrix in the question, or what you mentioned $A^TA$? that is my confusion.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER: Sorry, I am getting more confused. If you take the inner product of $v$ with $Av$ you get $v^T Av$. The matrix $A$ is positive semi definite if that quantity is $\ge 0$ for all $v$. The function $(u,v) \mapsto u^T Av$ is only an inner product if $A$ is positive **definite**. I have no idea where you are pulling $A^TA$ from.

Comment: @copper.hat  apparently the video was done and the audio added later. The lower right corner of the matrix was intended to be $c,$ and he begins completing the square on $a x^2 + 2bxy+c y^2 \; . \;$ Given the number and type of errors, I don't see this question as having any reasonable response from us.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks, I think you are correct. I fell into the vortex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

If $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$, then $A\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} ax+by \\ bx+ay \end{bmatrix}^T$ and
$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}^T A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}= a x^2+2bxy + a y^2$.

Comment: yes thats what i got. In the video it is mentioned that this is the inner product of $A$ with itself and the final quadratic from is same except last term was $by^2$ which should be as you wrote $ay^2$, so the expression above the "not" valid inner product of A with itself, right?